# How to add new array element from another method in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have some array( @private NSArray employees []; ) and method , which take string parameter( name of employees) and put this parameter in array. How I can do this with Objective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following,

Create a property,

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Initialise the array in your init method or somewhere else appropriate,

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Your method could look something like this,

```
- (void)addEmployeeName:(NSString *)employeeName {
   [self.array addObject:employeeName];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class Employee and use a type with your array.
For example:

```
NSArray<Employee*> * employees = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

At this point, your method will be:

```
-(Employee *)createEmployee:(NSString *)name{
   Employee *myEmpl = [[Employee alloc]init];
   [myEmpl setName:name];
   return myEmpl;
}
```

and you can add the object (of type Employee) in your array in this way:

```
[employees addObject:[self createEmployee]];
```

the same thing is possibile with an object of type NSString instead of Employee.
You can also avoid defining the type in your NSArray because Objective-C use the type inference