# Why I have error "No visible @interface for "NSArray<Employee *>" declares the selector "addObject:"?

Tags: objective-c

I need to insert Employee`s name into array, when I do it I receive this error. Whats wrong with my code?

```
#import "Employee.h"

@interface Organisation : NSObject

-(void) addEmployeeWithName:(NSString *)EmployeesName;

@end


@interface Organisation()

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Employee *> *employees;//     private var

@end


@implementation Organisation

-(void) addEmployeeWithName:(NSString *)EmployeesName
{
    [self.employees addObject:employeeName];// Error apear here
}


@end
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848767/how-to-add-new-array-element-from-another-method-in-objective-c

Comment: Because it doesn't have it. Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 6):

An [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray) is immutable. You want to use a [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray).

Comment: @SaharMax Yes, because you need to use a `NSMutableArray`. There's no `addObject:` method in `NSArray`.

Answer (score 6):

Replace below line:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Employee *> *employees;
```

with:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<Employee *> *employees;
```

Crash is because of `NSArray` doesn't declare or have any selector like `addObject:`.

There is no instance method like `addObjects:` in an `NSArray`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this method -> arrayByAddingObject

e.g. `[className.objectName **arrayByAddingObject**:@"addThisString"];`

Note: objectName is the NSArray of String values.